# Python - Why does requests.post return 200 without actually uploading the file?

Tags: python, python-requests

Note: I previously posted this question, but it was associated with another question where my question is not actually answered.

I'm trying to learn Python by converting some bash scripts into Python. I'm stuck on uploading a file to my web host. Here's what I'm trying along with the result:

```
import requests
user = '....'
password = '....'
myfile={'file': open('/Users/mnewman/Desktop/myports.txt' ,'rb')}
myurl = 'https://www.example.com/'
headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh;\ Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) \
         AppleWebKit/605.1.15(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.15"}
r = requests.post(url=myurl, data={}, files=myfile, \
        auth=(user, password), headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers)
```

```
200
{'Date': 'Sat, 12 Dec 2020 22:51:04 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Upgrade': 'h2,h2c', 
'Connection': 'Upgrade, Keep-Alive', 'Last-Modified': 'Sun, 30 Aug 2020 23:31:39 GMT', 
'Accept-Ranges': 'none', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 
'Content-Length': '1227', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=75', 'Content-Type': 
'text/html'}
```

Even thought the response code is 200, the file was not actually uploaded. How can I figure out why the file was not uploaded even though it returned a status code of 200?

Comment: That's a server-side issue, not one with requests.

Comment: Still have the same question. How can I figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: Check your Apache server logs?

Comment: As said the issue is on the server. It does not seem to use the typical error handling. Are you responsible for the server as well? If you are debug and fix the problem there, if not you might have to contact someone responsible for it.

Comment: This domain is hosted by HostGator. When I look at the page titled "Last 300 Error Log messages in reverse order", there are no errors listed at all. When I look at the raw access logs, my current IP address (dynamic) is not listed at all. I checked using the last three IP address that I have been given. (And, yeah, I do keep track of my IP address.)